# Am I supposed to add the name of a surgeon who had no contribution?

Tags: authorship, medicine

I'm need an urgent consultant regarding authorship rights.
Three years ago one of my professors asked me to write a surgical case report for one of his residents, later I found three similar cases and added to the article. I collected all data and followed all cases alone. The professor only gave the idea and neither the professor nor his resident made any contribution to writing the article or even reading what I've written. At last, they said this case in not worth publishing and we are not interested to publish your manuscript. They gave me permission to publish the article myself but the only document I have is a text message. Tonight, I got acceptance of my article and I want to make sure that I can publish that without the name of the surgeon. I have aknowledged their name.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE and thank you for your question. Unfortunately, as it stands, it is hard to understand who is who in your story, and what their potential contributions are. There are the professor, the resident, and the surgeon and several *they.* In particular who said that “this case in not worth publishing and we are not interested to publish your manuscript”? Also, what does *resident* mean in this context? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: There are many high quality sources online that address authorship questions under the banner of research integrity or publication ethics. This is just the first such result I get from a search: http://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html though there are many more, including field-specific guidance.

Comment: You need to ask these questions before submitting, not after acceptance.

Answer (score 5):

My take from your description is that the surgeon gave you his clear permission to publish without his name attached -- in the form of a written text message. Assuming that the wording in the text message is unambiguous, there ought to be nothing for you to worry about: He's expressed his opinion, and you're free to proceed.